# Should I change which answer I accept?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, stack-exchange

I asked [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47327/are-there-ways-to-concentrate-on-more-than-one-spell-at-a-time) question and accepted an answer, however, another answer incorporated the accepted answer and is now clearly better. 
Should I change my selection to the now better answer?

Answer (score 16):

Yes, you should. That is the nature of the site, finding what works for the asker.